# Histogram height with Matplotlib and Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to learn Matplotlib and graphing using python and I am trying to learn how to graph a histogram but I don't know how to get the height of the bars. 
Let's say I want 3 bars at 1,2,3 and height 10,20,30. How can I do this?

```
np.hist((1,2,3))
np.hist(((1,10),(2,20),(3,30)))
```

Are any of those right? 
When I put in the first one i get the x values but the heights are all 1. Please help

Comment: Matplotlib examples with code can be found here: http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html

Comment: yeah i looked there but they all use random generators to create a height, how can I input my own heights

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are trying to use matplotlib.pyplot and you must have used the 'hist' function for your first test.

I will just step back to make sure you get what a histogram is. When you plot a histogram of your vector, you plot the estimate of the density probability function. If you give your vector (1, 2, 3) as input to 'hist', your vector represents samples drawn from a random variable. By using this vector as input, you tell that you have drawn three points, one had the value 1, another the value 2 and the last one the value 3 hence the plot you get.

An answer could be this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = np.concatenate([np.ones(10), 2*np.ones(20), 3*np.ones(30)])
plt.hist(a)
```

So here, I create a with 10 samples of value 1, 20 samples of value 2 and 30 samples of value 3 and then I put them in one single vector (via concatenate).

I hope it helped.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean the `numpy.histogram()` function, which is designed to do the work for you to take a distribution of real-valued numbers and produce frequency bins from that.  You are giving the function a list containing three values, so the frequencies for those values are all 1--that is, there is a single `1`, a single `2`, and a single `3` in the array you pass.

What you are describing can be more easily done by making a simple bar chart.  You know what x values you want (1, 2, and 3), and you know what heights you want for each bin (10, 20, 30), so why not just do the following?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.bar([1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30])
```

[image: simple pyplot bar chart]

If you really want to produce a histogram with these frequency counts, you can construct one yourself by repeating `1` ten times, `2` twenty times, and `3` thirty times in an array:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data = [1] * 10 + [2] * 20 + [3] * 30
heights, bins = np.histogram(data, bins=[1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.bar(bins[0:3], heights)
```

[image: pyplot bar chart from histogram output]

Of course, you can also just skip creation of the histogram bins and heights and use `matplotlib.pyplot.hist` directly:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = [1] * 10 + [2] * 20 + [3] * 30
plt.hist(data, bins=[1, 2, 3, 4])
```

[image: histogram created directly using pyplot]